# Github Jekyll page behaves not properly

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-theme

I am trying to build Github Jekyll pages. Everything went fine and it gives the expected pages locally but the format of the page is really bad when it is in the Github page. On top of that any links on the page go to 404. I uploaded the basic jekyll page in github and it can be find at https://vinuvikraman.github.io/blogs/. Programs in Gemfile.lock have the similar version installed in Github.

How can I make the github page works properly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting `url` and `baseurl` in the config. Because it looks like the site expects it to be on the root domain and not at `/blog`. For example, the CSS file is refrenced at:

```
https://vinuvikraman.github.io/assets/main.css
```

But is actually at:

```
https://vinuvikraman.github.io/blogs/assets/main.css
```